# mysql nested IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this conditional in sql select syntax:

```
IF(u.sex = "M", "Male", "Female") AS sex
```

Problem is, even if value is null Female is returned.

How do i create logic, if NULL do nothing, else nested if I already have.

Something like

```
IF(u.sex IS NULL, NULL, IF(u.sex = "M", "Male", "Female")) AS sex
```

Comment: well your proposition is totally correct. You can also use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a select case.

```
SELECT CASE u.sex WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male'
WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female' ELSE 'Neither' END
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a `case`

```
case when u.sex = 'M' then 'Male'
     when u.sex = 'F' then 'Female'
     else NULL
end AS sex
```